# Makefile change filename into hidden files

Tags: string, makefile, gnu-make

All right I have 2 varables in my makefile. I want to iterate over the files in a variable and apply a transformation like the below.

```
cmain.cpp         ->   .cmain.depend
src/source.cpp    ->   src/.source.depend
```

How would I go about prepending a `.` to the beginning of the file name and changing the extension to depend with make? The array I want to transform is described by the below.

```
ALLSRC=$(shell find . -name '*.cpp')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALLSRC := $(shell find . -name '*.cpp')

#Get the filenames without the directory so we prepend the . to the right thing
FNAME := $(notdir $(ALLSRC))

#Add the .
FNAME := $(FNAME:%=.%)

#Put the directory names back
HIDDEN := $(join $(dir $(ALLSRC)),$(FNAME))
HIDDEN := $(HIDDEN:%=%.depend)

#Equivalent one liner
HIDDEN2 := $(patsubst %,%.depend,$(join $(dir $(ALLSRC)),$(patsubst %,.%,$(notdir $(ALLSRC)))))
.PHONY: all

all: $(HIDDEN)

# Copies the file in this example, but $< and $@ contain the before and after names, so you can do whatever you want to.
.%.depend : %
    cp "$<" "$@
```